# Path not found by DPInst

Tags: wix, driver, dpinst

I'm installing a driver using WiX with [DPInst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44191/Drivers-Installation-With-WiX), as per [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44191/Drivers-Installation-With-WiX). It works fine on Windows 7, but I'm trying it on Windows XP, and I get an error dialog popping up saying:

> ERROR: Path 'C:\Program Files\My Driver\package\driver.inf' not found

after which it prints a long usage message.

If I navigate to `C:\Program Files\My Driver\package\driver.inf` before I close the dialog, the file *is* there, at that location. In the `InstallExecuteSequence`, `InstallDriver` is set to happen Before `InstallServices`. What's going wrong?

**Note:** I've tried running DPInst from the command line, and I get the same error.

Also, I've tried moving DPInst into the same directory as the `.inf` and tried running it without the `/PATH` argument. Strangely, I still get the same error (that is, it gives the exact path to the `.inf` that it "can't find". This is very strange indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think that when you want to install a driver using DPInst.exe with /path you should only provide the path to the directory that contains the .inf file. That is: `dpinst.exe /path "C:\Program Files\My Driver\package\"`.